# Strange text scaling when system font is 125%

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here is full application xaml:

```
< Window x:Class="WpfApplication30.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
  < Border VerticalAlignment="Center"
          BorderBrush="Green"
          BorderThickness="1">
    < TextBlock Text="HELLO WORLD!"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="16" />
  </Border>
</Window>
```

When system font is set to 125% text is not in the center of the border. There is 7 pixels between top border and text and only 4 pixels between bottom border and text. How can I fix it?

UPD:
added

```
UseLayoutRounding="True"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

but diffrenece is still here: 8px and 6px

Comment: That is independent of the system font scaling. Instead, it is a feature of the chosen font. Try setting e.g. `FontSize="Arial"` to see the effect.

Comment: Font metrics are not that clean.  The space for leading and diacritics at the top and the space for descenders at the bottom isn't the usually the same.

Answer (score 3):

Font vertical centering is complicated, as the `TextBlock` will align to the center of the provisioned space so that any character from your selected Font fits this area. A basic overview why this is, can be found in the Wikipedia [Baseline (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) article

You can try to compensate for the specific font's metrics by using

- `GetEmHeight(FontStyle)`
- `GetCellAscent(FontStyle)`
- `GetCellDescent(FontStyle)`
- `GetLineSpacing(FontStyle)`

on the `FontFamily` class. And adjust the placement of the `TextBlock`.

Source: [How to: Obtain Font Metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But i would really advice against doing so as there are characters that could be using the space like `Á` and `j` which have different heights and line placement.

You might have better default layouting experience with fonts that are `monospaced` like `Consolas` which for `HELLO WORLD!` prints pretty much to the middle of the border.